# Plot multiple clValid graphs

Tags: r, plot

I have the following example using the mouse data. I compute the cluster validation scores for Internal and Stability methods using the [clValid](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/clValid/vignettes/clValid.pdf) function.

```
data(mouse)

express = mouse[,c("M1","M2","M3","NC1","NC2","NC3")]
rownames(express) = mouse$ID

intern = clValid(express, 2:6, clMethods=c("hierarchical","kmeans","pam"), validation="internal")
stab = clValid(express, 2:6, clMethods=c("hierarchical", "kmeans", "pam"), validation="stability")
```

I want to create one graph that has 5 columns and 2 rows.

The layout is the following.

```
        Internal - Dunn | Internal - Silhouette        |                 Stability - APN | Stability - AD       | Legend
Text beneath Internal graphs saying "Higher is better" | Text beneath Stability Graphs saying "Lower is better"
```

A preview of the graph is the following. Unfortunately, I can't get it to do what I want.

[image]

I have the following code for the graphs.

```
layout(matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
                6, 6, 6, 6, 6), nrow=2, byrow=TRUE),
       widths = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5),
       heights = c(1, 1))

par(mfrow=c(1,5),
    mar=c(5,5,2,1))

plot(intern, measure=c("Dunn"), legend=FALSE, main="",
     cex = 2, cex.lab = 2, cex.axis = 2)

plot(intern, measure=c("Silhouette"), legend=FALSE, main="",
     cex = 2, cex.lab = 2, cex.axis = 2)

plot(stab, measure=c("APN"), legend=FALSE, main="",
     cex = 2, cex.lab = 2, cex.axis = 2)

plot(stab, measure=c("AD"), legend=FALSE, main="",
     cex = 2, cex.lab = 2, cex.axis = 2)
```

What's going wrong:

1. Layout isn't working. I'm probably not providing the correct values. It has 1 row, 5 columns, instead of 2 rows, 5 columns.
2. I can't extract the legend from a plot object.

I also have the following questions.

1. Is it possible to plot clValid obejcts with ggplot2?
2. Can I extract the legend of a plot (not a ggplot2) object?

Comment: *Unfortunately, I can't get it to what I want.* ... what do you want? Please explain undesired results.

Comment: Sadder words were never written than “it didn’t work “.

Comment: "what do you want?" It's already described. 2 rows, 5 columns. First row: 4 graphs shown in the code posted. That's the part that works already. 5th column should have the legend only. Second row: Specific text beneath the graphs. Text beneath Internal graphs saying "Higher is better" | Text beneath Stability Graphs saying "Lower is better".